# FastReports pascalscript if

Tags: performance, if-statement, report, pascalscript, fastreport

I have a problem with an `IF` statement in FastReport.
I want to check if `ProgramName = ""`, then change `Memo1.Text = "ONLY FOR CALCULATION"`, if not, then "OTHER"

```
procedure rara(Sender: TfrxComponent);
var
ProgramName : sring;
begin
ProgramName := <Nest."PrgName">;

if ProgramName = "" then
begin                                
       memo1.Text = "ONLY FOR CALCULATION";                
       end
else
       begin
       Memo1.Tex = "OTHER";                                                             
       end
end;

end;
```

The error I see is:

> 'THEN' Expected

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I do not know Fast Report. But in general, in Pascal (Script) 1) You use single quotes, not double-quotes, for strings. 2) It's `string`, not `sring`. 3) It's `.Text`, not `.Tex`. 4) For assignment you use `:=`, not `=`.  5) You have more `ends` than `begins`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Fast Report, probably this script is the `OnBeforePrint` event handler for one of the `TfrxMemoView` components. The event handler should look like this (as @MartinPrikryl commented).

```
procedure Memo1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
var
   ProgramName : string;
begin
   ProgramName := <Nest."PrgName">;
   if ProgramName = '' then begin                                
      Memo1.Text := 'ONLY FOR CALCULATION';                
      end
   else begin
      Memo1.Text := 'OTHER';                                                             
   end
end;
```

Note, that `<Nest."PrgName">` returns the value for `PrgName` column from the `Nest` report dataset.